# ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [month] is missing. What caused my mistake

Tags: python, pandas

type here

```
import pandas as pd
import os


def process_xls(file_path):
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    (filepath, filename) = os.path.split(file_path)
    # 插入新列
    df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
    df.insert(0, 'name', os.path.splitext(filename)[0])

    null_positions = df.isnull()
    df.insert(2, 'time', pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Mon', 'Day', 'Hour']]))
    # 删除原来的四列数据
    df = df.drop(columns=['Year', 'Mon', 'Day', 'Hour'])
    return df


def process_folder(folder_path):
    for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if file_name.endswith('.xls'):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
            df = process_xls(file_path)
            new_file_name = 'new_' + file_name
            new_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, new_file_name)
            df.to_excel(new_file_path, index=False)


folder_path = r'H:\agriculture\QIXIANG\DATA_station'
process_folder(folder_path)
```

I have checked that there is no null value in the dataframe. What causes this error

I hope to merge four columns of year, month, day and hour data into one column of time

Answer (score 0):

Function [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) need `Month` column, so here need rename `Mon`:

```
df.insert(2, 'time', pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Mon', 'Day', 'Hour']].rename(columns={'Mon':'Month'})))
```